# Modifing the XSLTFilter class to apply the stylesheet xml2text.xsl

Tags: java, xml, xslt, filter

we have a task and don't find a solution. Can anyone help me?

Exercise 9.10
Modify the XSLTFilter class to apply the stylesheet xml2text.xsl if the resulting response is of type text/xml and dthe clients’s browser is the text-based Lynx tool (whose User-Agent value always starts with Lynx).

xml2text.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html><head><title>XML file</title></head><body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body></html>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:param name="ind" select="0"/> <xsl:call-template name="indent">
<xsl:with-param name="ind" select="$ind"/> </xsl:call-template> <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/> <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute::*"/> <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text><br/>
<xsl:apply-templates>
<xsl:with-param name="ind" select="$ind + 1"/>
</xsl:apply-templates> <xsl:call-template name="indent">
<xsl:with-param name="ind" select="$ind"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text><br/>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()"> <xsl:param name="ind"/> <xsl:call-template name="indent">
<xsl:with-param name="ind" select="$ind"/> </xsl:call-template>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><br/>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="attribute()">
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>="<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="indent">
<xsl:param name="ind"/>
<xsl:value-of select="for $i in (1 to $ind) return '&#xa0;&#xa0;'"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the XSLT-Filter

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.jdom2.*; 
import org.jdom2.transform.*; 
import org.jdom2.input.*; 
import org.jdom2.output.*; 

public class XSLTFilter implements Filter {
  ServletContext context;

  public void init(FilterConfig c) throws ServletException {
    context = c.getServletContext();
  }

  public void destroy() {}

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                       ServletResponse response, 
                       FilterChain chain) 
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest hreq = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse hresp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    boolean client_capable = 
      checkXSLTSupport(hreq.getHeader("User-Agent"));
    ServletResponse res;
    if (client_capable)
      res = response;
    else
      res = new BufferingResponseWrapper(hresp);
    chain.doFilter(request, res);
    context.log("XSLT transformation ok...");
    if (!client_capable) {
      try {
        hresp.setContentType("application/xhtml+xml");
        transform(((BufferingResponseWrapper)res).getReader(), 
                  response.getWriter());
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        context.log("XSLT transformation error", e);
        hresp.sendError(500, "XSLT transformation error");
      }
    }
  }

  boolean checkXSLTSupport(String user_agent) {
    if (user_agent==null)
      return false;
    return
      user_agent.indexOf("MSIE 5.5")!=-1 ||
      user_agent.indexOf("MSIE 6")!=-1 ||
      user_agent.indexOf("Gecko")!=-1;
  }

  void transform(Reader in, Writer out) 
      throws JDOMException, IOException {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", 
                       "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    SAXBuilder b = new SAXBuilder();
    Document d = b.build(in); 
    List pi = d.getContent(new org.jdom2.filter.ContentFilter
                           (org.jdom2.filter.ContentFilter.PI));
    String xsl = ((ProcessingInstruction)(pi.get(0)))
                 .getPseudoAttributeValue("href");
    XSLTransformer t = new XSLTransformer(xsl);
    Document h = t.transform(d);
    (new XMLOutputter()).output(h, out);
  }
}

class BufferingResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
  CharArrayWriter buffer;
  PrintWriter writer;

  public BufferingResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse res) {
    super(res);
    buffer = new CharArrayWriter();
    writer = new PrintWriter(buffer);
  }

  public PrintWriter getWriter() {
    return writer;
  }

  Reader getReader() {
    return new CharArrayReader(buffer.toCharArray());
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you have tried or what part of the problem you are struggling with. You need to ask a specific question, not just ask for coding assistance. I did notice that your stylesheet specifies version="2.0", but uses a construct that requires 3.0 (specifically, the use of a "for" clause in the final XPath expression.

Comment: @MichaelKay [For Expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-for-expressions) are defined in XPath 2.0 - of which you were one of the editors...

Comment: Whoops, sorry, it was let expressions that only came in in 3.1. Getting rusty, 2.0 was a long time ago.

Comment: From your deleted answer "My problem is, I don't understand the task." Well, I don't think it's our job on SO to fill in for the gaps in what you've been taught: we haven't been to the lectures and we don't know what they explained and what they didn't.